# Mostrar imagenes desde un fichero con php

Tags: php

En funcion de una variable $ID he de sacar una imagen u otra. El código funciona perfecto desde la 0-9, pero al llegar al numero 10 casca y me dice lo siguiente:

> ```
> Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\aa.php on line 7
> ```

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
session_start(); // session start
$getvalue = $_SESSION['ID']; // session get
$IMAGEN = $_SESSION['ID'];
$files = glob("IMAGENES/*.*");
if (count($files) > 0) { // make sure at least one image exists
        $img = $files["$IMAGEN"]; // first image
        echo "<img src='$img' height='150' width='150' /> ";
    } else {
       // possibly display a placeholder image?
    }
?>
```

Comment: `$img = $files["$IMAGEN"];` <-- si falla con 10, significa que sólo hay 10 archivos en tu carpeta, no 11... ¿que estás intentando hacer?

Comment: Estoy intentando sacar unas imagenes, cada una va vinculada a un empleado, por cada id de empleado habra otra imagen que se llame igual. ej : manolo  id=2 (y en el directorio habra otra imagen cuyo nombre sea 2)

Comment: Y en donde estás estableciendo el valor de la variable de sesión?

Comment: El valor de $_Session['ID'] lo establezco en otro script de php pero ese no es el problema, ya que he comprobado con echo que me esta sacando el valor correcto

Comment: ok, entonces, no deberías usar `$IMAGEN` dentro de `glob()` para buscar el archivo?

Answer (score 1):

Si sólo hay una imagen por trabajador sería algo tal que así, no hace falta utilizar el glob. ¿En `$IMAGEN` tienes la extensión del archivo?, si no es así habría que añadirlo tanto en el `file_exists` como en el código html del `img`.

```
<?php
session_start(); // session start
$getvalue = $_SESSION['ID']; // session get
$IMAGEN = $_SESSION['ID'];

if ( file_exists("IMAGENES/$IMAGEN") ) {
   echo "<img src='IMAGENES/$IMAGEN' height='150' width='150' /> ";
} else {
   // possibly display a placeholder image?
}
?>
```

En caso que un trabajador tuviera varias imágenes necesitarías un `glob` como estabas utilizando, pero tendrías que utilizar dentro del `glob` la variable `$IMAGEN`.